# Verify the following statement, $ \{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\} \in\ A \implies \{x,y\} \in\bigcup A $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My attempt at solving it:

> Let $ A = \{a,b,c,d\} $
>
> where: $ a = \{x\} , b = \{x,y\} , c = \{x,y,z\} $ and $ d = \{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\} $
>
> Then, $ \bigcup A  =a \cup\ b \cup\ c \cup\ d = \{x,y,z, \{x\},\{x,y\}\} $

I feel like this is correct, however I feel like my solution is kind of "brute forced" is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: You cannot assume that $a,b,c\in A$. That might not be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly assuming that $A$ is of a particular form. What if we just have $A=\{\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}\}$? Then you certainly can't write $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ as you do.

You can do it like this:

$\bigcup A = \bigcup_{a\in A} a=\{b\mid\text{there exists }a\in A\text{ such that }b\in a\}$.

And $\{x,y\}\in\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}\in A$ therefore $\{x,y\}\in\bigcup A$.